# Hide action (custom button) after use it

Tags: apex, trigger, javascript, visual-workflow

Hi everybody I have a detail page of X custom object that has a custom button (Action that display a Flow that has a LWC form). This button creates a record of Y custom object. I want that after the user creates the Z record of the Y custom object this button disappear.
I have the idea but I do not know how to implement it through code. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Use [dynamic actions](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2020/leverage-dynamic-forms-and-actions-to-build-experiences-your-users-will-love).

Comment: Hi @PhilW I tried with dynamic actions but the filters that are displayed in the dynamic action for my button does not work to me because I need that the button disappear after the user creates the record from that button. And I do not have anything in the filter of the dynamic action that could get that info from the new record.

Comment: If you cannot do it by simply testing if there is a related record, add some extra data captured (an extra field) when that button does the creation. Fundamentally you need data to drive the behaviour.

Comment: @PhilW the problem is that from the record of the object X where the button is a lot os students are going to use this button to create their records to upload their activities. So if I create a field in the record of the X object when the first student creates his record the field will get checked and the button will disappear and the other students wont be able to upload their activities.

Comment: If you cannot identify easily from the data using visibility filters you probably need to write a custom LWC to handle this then. Or leave the button active but tell the user (when they invoke it) they already did the action if their record already exists. The latter is a fairly common approach from UX discoverability perspective anyway.

Comment: @PhilW I will have to use the last approach that you said. Thanks